# Add my own HTML to WordPress website

Tags: html, wordpress

A client of mine would like me to go into their WordPress website and add a fixed button to the bottom-right. This button should be on every page.

I know HTML, JavaScript, CSS and PHP quite well, but have never used WordPress before and it seems a little frustrating.

I only need to add this button and link it to a URL, but I don't want to download additional plugins. Can I add my own HTML to a theme? I've heard of the ability to make Child Themes to prevent my additional HTML from getting wiped when the parent gets updated. How does this work and how can I use it to achieve the above?

Comment: The Appearance Editor Screen allows you to edit Theme files https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen

Comment: Have a look at WordPress's documentation :) https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Thanks @Nick, can you provide a brief description? Ex: `This link is about Child Themes` or `this will show you how to add your own html to an existing theme`

Comment: @Philip Yes I suppose 'take a look at the documentation' could be a valid answer to any question on SO. I've glanced over this particular doc and see nothing relevant to my question. Is there a particular section I should be focusing on?

Comment: @PaulG Try browsing the source files of the current used theme and find the part/module/file that is used everywhere (like a footer.php or similar) and then simply add the code there. The link can help you to find the right file.

Comment: Thanks @Philip! You're talking about viewing the raw files via FTP? Because in the WordPress Admin interface I see no source code.

Comment: Another reference of commonly used file/directory structure can be found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/

Comment: Yes if you have access, otherwise @Nick's suggestion is useful :)

Comment: @Philip Yep I have FTP access, and I could probably add what I need directly to the .html files there. But is this common practice? If the theme gets updated via wp-admin will my html still be there?

Comment: @PaulG I'm not sure, but this is just a quick fix to get the button up there.

Answer (score 2):

Child themes are the typical way to modify an existing theme, so that you can still update the original theme as its developer releases new versions. It is correct that updating the theme would wipe out your changes, if you don't use a child theme.

I've only made a couple child themes myself, but I found this documentation helpful:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

For modifying template files like the footer, the first section "Creating a Child Theme from an Unmodified Parent Theme" is the minimum to get started. The `style.css` file contains metadata that tells WordPress about the child theme and its parent, even if you don't add any styles. The functions.php file makes sure both themes' stylesheets are loaded, and can be used for other functions later. The page above has some code you can mostly copy and paste, with some changes for your site's specifics.

Once the child theme exists, you can copy footer.php from the original theme into the child's directory, and modify it as needed. Keep in mind that since you are overriding the original theme's footer.php, if there are later changes in the parent theme's footer.php, you may need to manually update your copy, to combine their changes with your site-specific code.

If you have a separate site or development environment where you can test your child theme first, I'd recommend using that, then copying it to the live site when it's ready.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do this within your Wordpress Theme / Template files.

You'd have to learn the architecture of Wordpress CMS `(mostly)` but also your applied theme you'd be customizing and adding this feature. You'll have to know what `.php` files drive what pages and where you can add this feature.

If you don't want to mess with both any core Wordpress CMS files nor your original applied 'Theme' files; you can consider creating a 'child theme' or 'plugin' to extend the features and functionality; this way.

Please start by understanding Wordpress CMS further. Here's a good article: 'http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-file-and-directory-structure/' also check http://wordpress.org

Hope this helps, g'luck!

Answer (score 0):

Building a child theme is ultimately the best thing to do, as any future theme edits for the client can be done there. Here's [an article on WP child theme creation](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/).

A quicker way should be mentioned, although it can be limiting: Go to Dashboard/Appearance/Widgets, make a new Text widget and place into your footer region. This is assuming, of course, that the theme you're using has a footer region defined (most do). In the widget, use some HTML like this: 
`<div style="float: right; width: 60px; background-color: red"><a href="#anchor" style="color: white">BUTTON</a></div>`